A movie about a lorry in space transporting robots?
I remember I once saw a movie about a space trucker who had to transport some robots back to earth. He also got some canteen worker to agree to marry him if he got her back to earth. Also I remember the robots waking up before he got to earth and he had to use a remote to shut them down or something.
Does anybody remember the name of this movie?

Space Truckers (1996):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Truckers

The story concerns John Canyon, one of the last independent space transport entrepreneurs. Bad times have forced him to carry suspicious cargo to Earth without asking questions. During the flight the cargo turns out to be a multitude of virtually unstoppable killer robots.
[John Canyon] and his two passengers - Cindy, a waitress who has promised to marry him in exchange for a ride to Earth to see her mother, and Mike, an up-and-coming trucker working for the company - take on a deal to transport "sex dolls" to Earth

